# Using BackgroundWorker from VBScript

Tags: c#, vbscript, backgroundworker, installshield

I created such code to use BackgroundWorker from another class:

```
    public void BackgroundWorkerTest()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        while (bw.IsBusy) 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        string connStr = "<conn_str>";
        string path = "";
        MyClass.StaticMethod(string1, string2, worker);
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        string message = e.UserState.ToString();
    }

    private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string progress = "Done.";
    }
```

From MyClass.StaticMethod() I call

```
    worker.ReportProgress(percents, message);
```

to send progress information. Is it possible to use above code (mentioned in BackgroundWorkerTest() method) or similar in VBScript? It is necessary to output progress information from VBScript (in InstallShield). Does it have enough capabilities for this?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is a .NET class, and can only be used in a .NET program.

Comment: PowerShell should work too.

Comment: What do You mean, Ansgar?

Comment: What project type are you using in InstallShield?  InstallScript, Basic MSI, InstallScript MSI?

Comment: @John Saunders- FWIW, there are mechanisms for calling managed code from InstallShield and/or Windows Installer based installers.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: allow me to be more specific: BackgroundWorker is a .NET class, and can only be called from where .NET classes can  be called, which does not include "from VBScript".

Comment: I assume you've heard of ComVisible. Regardless, VBScript has no place in an installer in my book anyways. There are plenty of better options to run managed code in an installer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an MSI based InstallShield project type, google Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  DTF is an SDK for creating managed code custom actions to be run inside MSI's.

If you are using an InstallScript project type, google DotNetCoCreateObject (InstallScript function).

Regardless, I suggest making sure you aren't reinventing the wheel. (I saw your reference to connection string. )

Comment: I just have dll which installs and creates DB structure: functions, tables, privileges, etc. It is used in a web-service during startup. However there was an idea to put this dll call inside installation process. Do not want to develop another version for VBS if existing C# works fine.

Comment: From an installer perspective, that's reinventing the wheel.  The better approach is to script your database out to SQL files and have InstallShield handle executing them for you.

Comment: Db is scripted by many scripts, designed special way to always install or upgrade to actual DB version. Need to remake all this logic in InstallShield: tables, roles, function, privileges, upgrades, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you are already in a good position. If your scripts can handle  things like if not exist table create table, if not exist column alter table  then just plug it all into InstallShield's SQL Scripts view.

Comment: I see, some of this logic is handled in C#, of course it is possible to move to SQL.

Comment: On the other hand, you could always run it outside of the installer / after the installer.  This is what Team Foundation Server does for example.  If you attach a project collection of an older schema, the system will run the upgrade scripts to the current schema.  Install time may or may not be the optimal time for you. YMMV.

Comment: Sure, I did this to start on service startup, works fine. Customer want to try another variant.